# Dirac equation in curved space-time with differential forms

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, dirac-equation

The title says it all essentially.  I am wondering if there is a way to write the Dirac equation in any space-time in the language of differential forms.  I know in Minkowski space it is possible to pass from the tensor form of the equation to the $i(\text{d} + \delta)\omega = m \omega$ form.  Is there a generalization to curved space-times, and if so, could you provide some references?

Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, because I still didn't go through spinor fields in curved spacetimes in full detail. But the LHS operator should act on a spinor field and not a differential form and AFAIK a spinor field is a section of one associated bundle to the Lorentz frame bundle. So from this POV I can't see how trying to rewrite Dirac's equation with differential forms would work. I could be totally mistaken though.

Comment: @user1620696 One can rewrite the spinor as a $4 \times 4$ matrix  and make a map from the gamma matrices as a basis for $4 \times 4$ matrices, and the $dx^{\mu}$s coordinate basis in the language of forms.  One ends up with a four-fold degeneracy of the Dirac equation but they are four identical copies, so it's harmless.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so I have to leave a reply.

I know of a good reference where the authors put a free massive spinor field in Euclidean $AdS_5$

[Spinors and the AdS/CFT correspondence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9803251.pdf)

You are mainly interested in sections 2 and 3 I guess with the vielbeins, the spin connections and the explicit calculations. I guess that after studying the general ideas, you can perform analogous calculations on different curved manifolds.

I hope that this covers you, at least partially.

Cheers!!!